# My tabBar disappeared after adding other ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uikit

It is visible if i comment part where i set my ViewControllers.
It is like been superimposed by other ViewControllers. Cause it works but i can't see it.
When i tap bottom parts of screen color of screen changes to colors which i assign to controllers.

[My run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4qCl.png)

```
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow()
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        window?.rootViewController = MusicTabBarController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

}
```

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
    }

}
```

```
class SearchViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .orange
    }

}
```

these are my SceneDelegate and ViewControllers codes, code of my main controller is on the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Zhiger Sairan

your TabBar isn't disappeared. As I can see on view debugger [image]
You have to set image or/and title to your tabbarItem in UIViewControllers.

It's small code example, that helps:

```
class MusicTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .gray
        
        let searchVC = SearchViewController()
        searchVC.tabBarItem.title = "SearchViewController"
        let playerVC = ViewController()
        playerVC.tabBarItem.title = "ViewController"
        viewControllers = [
            searchVC,
            playerVC
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it works, but how to make it not hidden behind the ViewControllers? I want my tabBar looks like this guy's tabBar. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a8f1m1kSELs&t=333s

Answer (score 0):

this piece of code helped to solve my problem

```
 let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = .white
    tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBar.standardAppearance
```